# Displaying an item that meets 2 conditions in a SQL database in a Webform label

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

[image]I'm completely new to SQL, so please bear with me.

I'm basically trying to display an item that meets 2 conditions within an SQL database in a Webform on Visual Studio using C#.

The table consists of words according to category and level(easy, medium, hard). The webform allows the user to select multiple categories using check boxes and the level via a drop down list.

I would like to display a single word within the database depending on which level and which category has been chosen.

I've attached a picture of what the table looks like.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you[image]

Comment: Are "flora", "space", and "wildlife" the categories?  And if so, there are multiple words for any "level" and category, so how do you want to choose just one?  At random? the first one?

Comment: You say something about two conditions. Would you be able to share those conditions? I assume one of them is level. What is the other one? And fwiw I would suggest that your table design is simply awful. You have a VERY bad design here. You should have a row for EACH word, not what you have here.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Correct those are the categories. Basically if the user selects the following Checkboxes (Flora, Space, Wildlife) and a particular level... A word is selected from the database and displayed. 
I understand Sean, I shall edit the database to create a row for each word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the reason you were struggling with a query here is because the data model is less than optimal. Here is better model for your words.

```
create table Words
(
    LevelID int
    , CategoryID int
    , Word varchar(50)
)

create table WordLevel
(
    LevelID int
    , LevelDescription varchar(25)
)

create table Category
(
    CategoryID int
    , CategoryDescription varchar(50)
)

insert WordLevel
select 1, 'Easy' union all
select 2, 'Medium' union all
select 3, 'Hard'

insert Category
select 1, 'flora' union all
select 2, 'space' union all
select 3, 'wildlife'

insert Words
select 1, 1, 'sunflower' union all
select 1, 2, 'pluto' union all
select 1, 3, 'lion'

select * --of course you would only include the columns you actually need here
from Words w
join Category c on c.CategoryID = w.CategoryID
join WordLevel wl on wl.LevelID = w.LevelID
where w.LevelID = 1
    and c.CategoryDescription = 'space'
```

Comment: Thank you so much @SeanLange... Your help is much appreciated Sir!

Comment: Hopefully that helps. What I didn't include here is primary and foreign keys. If you add those you will have a pretty solid data structure that allows things like new categories and new levels with no modification to your database.